# When mistakes reaches 5, this code continues to run while mistakes stagnate at 5, why is this?

Tags: python

```
import random
number = random.randint(1,100)
mistakes = 0
```

## function begins here

```
def numberguesser(number,mistakes):
    guess = int(input("Guess?"))
    if guess < number:
        mistakes += 1
        print("Guess is too low, Mistakes:", mistakes)
    if guess > number:
        mistakes += 1
        print("Guess is too high, Mistakes:", mistakes)
    if guess == number:
        print ("Correct!")
```

## This is where I think the mistake is happening as it continues to ask for guesses after the mistakes reach five

```
    while guess != number and mistakes < 5:
        numberguesser(number, mistakes)
numberguesser(number, mistakes)
```

Comment: this is not the same `mistakes`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you know I swear I've seen this before :p

Comment: you're incrementing the local variable/parameter, where you're checking for the global one

Comment: @JoelBerkeley be my guest, suggest a good duplicate, by all means

Comment: don't pass `mistakes`, make it global. Oh, bar that, using globals suck.

Comment: Your parameters `number` and `mistakes` define function-local variables that are separate from the global variables `number` and `mistakes`, even though you initialize them using the global variables.

Comment: well, don't create a function and paste the code directly: you'll be fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem was your mistake variable is global, and you need say that inside de function. And you don't need pass the number and mistake by param, you can pass only your guess, case you want to, even the guess you can put inside the function :)
Try the follow code, isn't the best solution, but should workfine:

```
import random
number = random.randint(1, 100)
mistakes = guess = 0

def numberguesser(guess):
  global mistakes, number # explicit says the global var

  if guess < number:
    mistakes += 1
    print("Guess is too low, Mistakes:", mistakes)
  elif guess > number:
    mistakes += 1
    print("Guess is too high, Mistakes:", mistakes)
  elif guess == number:
      print ("Correct!")

while guess != number and mistakes < 5:
  guess = int(input("Guess?"))
  numberguesser(guess)
```